# Should I depend on gems I'm extending?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Suppose there's gem that implements authentication strategy for Warden or a storage engine for Paperclip or an ActiveRecord database adapter. Should it include the gems it supposed to be used with as regular dependencies? If so, what should be the version constraints? It certainly has to include "parent" gems as development dependencies but what about regular ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s all up to you. Unless you rely in your code on gem presence (read: surround all your code with `if const_defined?('Paperclip')` or like,) your gem might gracefully reject to operate unless the necessary dependencies are already included in the target project. The version should correspond the version you have your code tested against.

As a good example of the case when direct dependence is *not* a good choice, would be the “umbrella” gem, simplifying work with different, say, authorization engines. One won’t require all these devises, pundits, and family. Instead one should do “clever” initialization:

```
case
when Kernel.const_defined?('Devise')
  Logger.debug 'Will initialize Devise bridge.'
  # initialization of bindings etc.
when Kernel.const_defined?('Pundit')
  Logger.debug 'Will use Pundit bridge.'
  # initialization of bindings etc.
...
else
  Logger.warn 'No authorization backend found.'
  raise 
end
```

Or, imagine the logger, that might send airbrakes. For the logger to operate, the airbrake presense is not crucial. Hence one might check the presence of airbrake gem in the target project and switch the additional functionality on on success.

Hope it helps.